# Chatbase supports other languages (Portuguese)?

Tags: chatbase

I want to know if chatbase.com supports others language than English. My bot talks in Portuguese.

I saw the chatbase.com documentation, but doesn't found it there.

Advance, my chatbot has IBM Watson technology. Chatbase works properly with it, sure?

Answer (score 0):

All Chatbase standard reports support UTF8 characters. Some of the advanced features such as clustering are currently only available for English and Spanish.

You can set up a custom server to server integration with any platform. Please see this [guide](https://chatbase.com/documentation/generic) for details on how to format your messages into a JSON payload to upload to Chatbase.